# Activator.CreateInstance works in one method but throws AmbiguousMatchException in another

Tags: c#, reflection

I have two generic methods in the same class, and each uses exactly the same code to create instances. One works, the other throws an AmbiguousMatchException.  Here is the code:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, AccessBase> _dictionary;

public static T Access<T>(Type type) where T : AccessBase
{
    T instantiated;

    if (_dictionary.ContainsKey(type))
    {
        instantiated = _dictionary[type] as T;
    }
    else
    {
        instantiated = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type, _manager); //<- Works!
        _dictionary.Add(type, instantiated);
    }

    return instantiated;
}        

public static void RegisterAccess<T>(Type type) where T : AccessBase
{
    if (type == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
    }

    if (_dictionary.ContainsKey(type))
    {
        return;
    }

    var instantiated = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type, _manager); //<- Fails!
    if (instantiated == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(type)} cannot be registered");
    }

    _dictionary.Add(type, instantiated);
}
```

I would welcome any suggestions as to why and what to do about it... I have been tearing what is left of my hair out over this one!

Comment: Give us a program *we can actually run* that demonstrates the problem. In creating such a program you'll either figure it out yourself, or you'll create a program where it is much easier to figure it out.

Comment: Hi Eric, I cannot see how to do that within a publishable size because of the amount of code involved.  It would require an entire framework to host it as in the main application, plus the entire data hierarchy. I will try to cut it down and still replicate the issue but cannot see how to achieve it right now. I was hoping I was doing something obvious and stupid that someone might recognise within the supplied code, no such luck I guess!

Comment: Side question... Does `typeof(T) == type`? Or is it expected to be some type in a hierarchy? If the former you could ditch the parameter to the method entirely

Comment: Well, first of all, to check on null you should use `Activator.CreateInstance(type, _manager) as T`, not a cast. And secondly, why are you using `var` if you know the type? Just replace it with `T`.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: Yes, both are the same in normal usage.  The type is expected to be a class that inherits from AccessBase e.g. AccessLogAccess: AccessBase.  There are a huge number of these which are registered in the framework by the plugin modules and the application for the types available to all modules and system code.

Comment: @Nyerguds: I have tried both as T and the cast, but both behave the same.  Var and T have the same effect, but Resharper suggests using var... and that is generally a good guide!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all of you for your input. I finally found the problem, which as it turns out is quite simple actually.  At the point of failure the value of the _manager field is null...  As soon as it is no longer null, it works.

To trap this I tried calling the first method at the same time as the second, and both failed.  Tracking it through, I determined that the cause was the null value, since if you do it later in the process it works fine.

The original purpose of the code was to pre-register the access classes so that when they are needed they are ready to go and avoid the constant 'new' calls to generate these classes as they are needed.  Given that it is now clear that this cannot happen at that point, the question is whether this is required at all.  If we do it at a later point, there is not much reason to do it as it will get repeated every time a database is opened with each one not being added as it already exists.

I think we will end up abandoning the process that uses the second method, the pre-registration, in favour of the first method which is already used anyway and which automatically adds the instantiated classes only when they are needed and which already works fine at the later point.